# jQuery Ajax is not working in Cake PHP 3.1

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp

I am using CakePHP 3.1 along with jQuery Ajax.

Below is my form code:

```
echo $this->Form->textarea('comment',array('class'=>'ckeditor','id'=>'comment1'));

    echo $this->Form->button('Send',array('id'=>'save'));
```

And my ajax code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$( document ).ready(function() {

     $("#save").click(function () {    
        var str = $( "#comment1" ).val();
        $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo Router::url(array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'view'));?>" ,
        data : {comment:str},
        success: function (data)
        {
            alert(data);  
        }   

        });

        });

    });

</script>
```

And my corresponding action is,

```
public function view($id = null) {
if($this->request->is('ajax')){

                $this->layout = 'ajax';
                $this->render('ajax');
                $na=$_POST['comment'];
                echo $na;
}
}
```

I don't know what is the problem is. It's not calling the corresponding action.

Comment: how does the url look like and what is the error in the console

Comment: @madalin ivascu no data passed to the view action

Comment: How can you tell that no data is passed, can you see in chrome or firefox network tab what is sent? And do not use $_POST in cake, you should get data with `$this->request->data` like in [here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#request-body-data)

Comment: @skywalker why i am telling , data is not passed means, in the view action , i have used echo to respond. But I could not seen any response from view action.

Answer (score 1):

I believe my problem was that, I used CKEditor. So to get the value of CKEditor textarea, we need to use the following code:

```
echo $this->Form->textarea('comment',array('class'=>'ckeditor','id'=>'editor1'));
    echo $this->Form->button('Send',array('id'=>'save'));
```

Instead of  this `var str = $( "#comment1" ).val();` we need to use

```
var value = CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].getData();
```